# Issue with installing Python in Linux / CentOS

Tags: python

Issue with installing Python in Linux / CentOS?

I downloaded and unzipped this tar file: Python-2.7.9.tgz
https://www.python.org/downloads/

When I run setup.py I get below error message. Also would anyone know how to upgrade python 2.6 to 2.7 in CentOS?

```
$python setup.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
import sysconfig
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

Best,

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have downloaded the source code of python so you have to compile source code then install.

Follow the instructions here: http://bugs.python.org/issue11353

Answer (score 1):

To install python first extract the archive and then configure make & make install.

```
tar -xvf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
./configure
make
make install
```

If you run the commands verbatim, you'll have to run them as `root` or `sudo`.

alternatively, (and preferably), install python in a different location by providing a prefix during the install.

edit: after installing a different python interpreter, run the following

```
whereis python2.7
```

This should tell you where python 2.7.9 has been installed (look for the path that has `bin` in it). then you can either start the interpreter using the full path or create a symlink to it.

```
ln -sf <path/to/bin/python2.7> /usr/local/bin/python27
```

Comment: I did and it installed but I see I have 2.6 python not 2.7

Comment: ah, so it seems that you need to create a symlink to python2.7 or call the interpreter with its full path.

Comment: $ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python27
ln: accessing `/usr/local/bin/python27': Too many levels of symbolic links

Comment: what happens if you start the python 2.7 interpreter with this command? `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`